# How to access the raw value of an associated value in an enum in Swift?

Tags: swift, enums

how to access the raw value of, for instance, "TmdbImageSize.backdrop(.original).rawValue" ? I don't know how to make it work or if it's even possible. Thanks for your help

```
enum TmdbBackdropSize: String {
    case w300, w780, w1280
    case original
}

enum TmdbLogoSize: String {
    case w45, w92, w154, w185, w300, w500
    case original
}

enum TmdbPosterSize: String {
    case w92, w154, w185, w342, w500, w780
    case original
}

enum TmdbProfileSize: String {
    case w45, w185
    case h632
    case original
}

enum TmdbImageSize {
    case backdrop (TmdbBackdropSize)
    case logo (TmdbLogoSize)
    case poster (TmdbPosterSize)
    case profile (TmdbProfileSize)
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to get `.original` from `TmdbImageSize.backdrop(.original)`? If yes, I'd suggest you create `var raw: String { switch self { case .backdrop(let size): return size.rawValue, case ....}}` on `TmdbImageSize`. It'd be simpler then.

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/enumerations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enums with associated values in Swift don't have an inherent "rawValue" property like enums conforming to RawRepresentable. Each case's associated value needs to be handled explicitly.

In your case, to access the raw value of *TmdbImageSize.backdrop(.original)*, you need to handle it directly in the enum:

```
enum TmdbBackdropSize: String {
    case w300, w780, w1280
    case original
}

enum TmdbLogoSize: String {
    case w45, w92, w154, w185, w300, w500
    case original
}

enum TmdbPosterSize: String {
    case w92, w154, w185, w342, w500, w780
    case original
}

enum TmdbProfileSize: String {
    case w45, w185
    case h632
    case original
}


enum TmdbImageSize {
    case backdrop(TmdbBackdropSize)
    case logo(TmdbLogoSize)
    case poster(TmdbPosterSize)
    case profile(TmdbProfileSize)

    func rawValue() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .backdrop(let size):
            return size.rawValue
        // handle other cases if needed...
        }
    }
}

// Example usage
let imageSize = TmdbImageSize.backdrop(.original)
let rawValue = imageSize.rawValue()
print(rawValue)
```

Here, I've added a method **rawValue** to the **TmdbImageSize** enum that extracts the raw value from the associated enum case. Now, you can call *imageSize.rawValue()* to obtain the raw value.

Comment: How do you know that the enums associated values are all enums whose raw value is a String? The function `rawValue()` assumes a lot of things. I suggest you only show an example(s) of how to get a raw value from a single case.